# Determine functions defined between two points in script

Tags: powershell

How would I be able to determine what functions are defined between two points of a script?

e.g.

```
function dontCare()
{}
# Start here
function A()
{}

function B()
{}
# Know that A and B have been defined
```

I was thinking about using `Get_ChildItem function:*` and taking the difference at the two points, but that wouldn't work if the functions are already defined.

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the script, list all functions and ase you logic on the result.

```
$content = Get-Content .\script.ps1
$tokens = [System.Management.Automation.PSParser]::Tokenize($content,[ref]$null)

for($i=0; $i -lt $tokens.Count; $i++)
{
    if($tokens[$i].Content -eq 'function')
    {
        $tokens[$i+1]
    }
}
```

In v, you can also use the AST, see the  ISE function explorer add-on by Ravi:
http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=2518

Comment: Thanks, though I'd like to do it within the script itself as I also want to make it work remotely as well.

Comment: You can tokenize the current script, grab it's path and you're good to go

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how that would work: if you define functions in script you should know you define them. Are you dot-sourcing other script?

If not, than this should get you there (even if A and B were defined before script runs):

```
# NewScript.ps1
function dontCare()
{}
# Start here
$Me = (Resolve-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).ProviderPath

$defined = ls function: | 
    where { $_.ScriptBlock.File -eq $Me } |
    foreach { $_.Name }

function A()
{}

function B()
{}
# Know that A and B have been defined
ls function: |
    where { 
        $_.ScriptBlock.File -eq $Me -and
        $defined -notcontains $_.Name
    } |
    foreach { $_.Name }
# end of script body, trying it...

.\NewScript.ps1
A
B
```

In case you are dotsourcing a script, it gets even easier:

```
# NewScript2.ps1
function dontCare2()
{}
# Start here
$He = (Resolve-Path -Path .\NewScript.ps1).ProviderPath

. $He | Out-Null

ls function: |
    where { 
        $_.ScriptBlock.File -eq $He
    } |
    foreach { $_.Name }
# end of script body, trying it...

.\NewScript2.ps1
A
B
dontCare
```

For me only dot-sourcing scenario makes some sense (you use outside source so can not be sure what it defines) but I assumed you may need both... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$exists = get-command -erroraction silentlycontinue A
```

You could then branch your logic depending on the result.

Comment: That requires knowing that I'm looking for a function called A. I'd like to be able to discover any arbitrary function defined between two points